# Cannot resolve method postdelayed

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Alright, this is my code:

```
final TextToSpeech ttv = new TextToSpeech(MainActivity.this, new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {


        public void onInit(int status) {
            ttv.setLanguage(Locale.US);
            Log.e("Init", "Success");
            ttvInit = true;
            // wait a little for the initialization to complete
            Handler h = new Handler();
            h.postDelayed(new Runnable()
            {
            public void run() {
                ttv.speak(textSpeech.getText().toString(),TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH,null);
            }
        }, 400);}

    else {
        System.out.println("Something went wrong.");
    }
        }
```

but i'm getting an error "Cannot resolve method 'postDelayed(java.lung.Runnable, int)'

EDIT:
it's telling me now that it's unused:
http://www.igreklik.com/slike/viewer.php?file=75221279105193055086.png&file_imgur=HPjDlfa.png

Answer (score 14):

Check your import for:

```
import android.os.Handler;
```

and change your code to this (your "else" statement is incorrect):

```
final TextToSpeech ttv = new TextToSpeech(MainActivity.this, new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {

    public void onInit(int status) {
        ttv.setLanguage(Locale.US);
        Log.e("Init", "Success");
        ttvInit = true;
        // wait a little for the initialization to complete
        Handler h = new Handler();
        h.postDelayed(new Runnable()
            {
            public void run() {
                ttv.speak(textSpeech.getText().toString(),TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH,null);
            }
        }, 400);
    }
 });
```

Comment: one '}' was missing and i added it, then i got error that ')' and ';' is missing, and i added them as well, but now this is the error: "Error:(35, 9) error: <anonymous cannon.gaming.physicsdroid.MainActivity$1> is not abstract and does not override abstract method onInit(int) in OnInitListener".
I edited my post, so you can see how my code looks now

Comment: now i deleted the one ttv = new line because i had 2, but now it says the whole thing is unused

Answer (score 0):

I just realize that there is a also a class named "Handler" from java.util.logging. You probably import the wrong one as me. Delete it and `import android.os.Handler` instead.