# Splash screen using handler

Tags: handler, using, splash-screen

i want to make splash screen using handler but it is showing an error
postDelayed(java.lang.Runnable,long) in android.os.Handler cannot be applied to anonymous.java.lang.runnable
what should i do to make it correct my code is

[image]

Comment: check which handler you import?Possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28252514/5110595)

Comment: import android.os.Handler; i have imported this handler

Comment: i post the ans, have look.

Comment: please post your code directly in the question not through a screen shot

Answer (score 0):

Your handler should be like this:

```
 final Handler handler = new Handler();
       handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
       @Override
       public void run() {

        }
      }, 100);
```

Comment: thanks for answering but its still not working errors are removed but the activity is stopped working

Answer (score 0):

You need to attach the intent to a context as Runnable lines are not attached by default. Just add `ActivityName.this.startActivity(...)` or `mContext.startActivity(...)` if you are in a fragment. this should solve the problem.

```
Handler h = new Handler();

h.postDelayed(new Runnable(){

@Override
public void run(){

SplashyActivity.this.startActivity(new Intent(SplashyActivity.this,MainActivity.class));
finish();

}}, 3000);
```